# Android GridLayout Dividers

Tags: android, border, android-gridlayout, divider

Why would Android not include the ability to border cells in a gridlayout? I have read multiple post of several ways to do this. One method I have tried with limited success is below. My problem is the horizontal line divider. When execute with the vertical and horizontal code in place, my grid ends up with cells blocked out so the text is not visible in the cell. If I remove the horizontal code, I get perfect vertical lines at each column as expected. Any idea as to what is wrong.  I was able to use the same method to create gridlines on a table. The gridlayout is inside a horizontal scroll which is inside a vertical scroll. Gridlayout background is black. So I should end up with blue cells and black divider lines.

```
 for (int y = 0; y < rownum; y++) {
 cols = 0;
 while (cols < columnum) {
  TextView textViewD = new TextView(this);
  textViewD.setTextSize(18);
  textViewD.setWidth(300);
  textViewD.setHeight(75);
  textViewD.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  textViewD.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
   textViewD.setText(title);
  //CREATE VERTICAL DIVIDER LINES
            View v = new View(this);
            v.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(3, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    cols++;
    gridLayoutE.addView(textViewD);

    }

    //CREATE HORIZONTAL DIVIDER LINES

               View v1 = new View(this);
        v1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 3));
        v1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        gridLayoutE.addView(v1);

   }
```

[image]

Edit:
This is what I found on other post about setting margins of textView

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)textViewD.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
            textViewD.setLayoutParams(params);

I don't have a LinearLayout, when I attempt this, it crashes.

Comment: Can you include an image on how you want it to look like?

Comment: I attached image of anticipated outcome.

Comment: Do you make the whole View in code without xml?

Comment: What is the parent view of textView!? There is no one? Is it itself?

Comment: This is trick to arrive to your because the background of your gridlayout is black already make the layout of textview to setparams match parent then apply some margins lets say 2. This will make the black colour to appear because margin will make the view adjust a little do you get it?

Comment: So by doing this, I don't need to create the lines? I would be using the background of the gridlayout as the lines, correct?

Comment: Yeah you dont need the lines try commenting them off and try the solution I have given you! It will result to the same view as you have shown and you will simply adjust the margins to your need!

Comment: Xenolion, your solution makes perfect sense but I am unable to make it work. The textview is made dynamically and added to the gridlayout. I'm not sure on how to set the textView margin. I have found other post, but looks like they all reference a layout parent to the textView. When I attempt to reference the gridlayout to get the parameters, there is an error that you can't cast textView to the GridLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: Xenolion, after studying a little more I have gotten it to work. Thank you for the direction. I created a LinearLayout as the parent and adjusted margins, works great.

Comment: Oooooh sorry I was offline for too long! But I am glad you solved your problem nicely **Happy Coding!**. I will simply post the direction as an answer hoping to help someone in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The other simple tricky way to get the same `View` like you want is:**
Because the background of your `GridLayout` is black already, Put your `TextView` inside another layout lets say `LinearLayout` make the layout of `Textview` to setparams `MATCH_PARENT` then apply some margins lets say `2` and then add the whole view(`LinearLayout` as a root). This will make the black colour to appear because margin will make the view adjust a little and therefore show some sort of boundaries just like you have shown in your image! Using this way will simplify the job and therefore you do not need to create divider lines be it horizontal nor vertical!

Answer (score 2):

For those who may run into a similar situation, as suggested by Xenolion, here is what I ended up doing.

```
for (int y = 0; y < rownum; y++) {
cols = 0;
while (cols < columnum) {
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
            parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 params.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);  //CREATES DIVIDER LINES
 TextView textViewD = new TextView(this);
 textViewD.setTextSize(18);
 textViewD.setWidth(300);
 textViewD.setHeight(75);
 textViewD.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
 textViewD.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
 textViewD.setText(title);
 textViewD.setLayoutParams(params);
 parent.addView(textViewD);
 cols++;
 gridLayoutE.addView(parent);
}
```

}

Comment: Yeah that's nice!

Comment: the above code is not quite right. Black should be GridLayout's background, rather than the LinearLayout. In fact, the LinearLayout should use White background.